# Identification of Mold

Tags: drywall, safety, mold, plaster

I am working with some old plaster and a few days after it set, I found that pink mold or fungus appears to be growing on it. See attached photo.

Please help me identify what type of mold this is and if it is dangerous to my health.

Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Take a sample and send it for testing. No other way to know for sure. Could be necrotising fasciitus…

Comment: Too many types of molds/fungus to ID by picture alone.  Will need to have a sample tested, probably local health department can help.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what you have there.  It almost looks like someone's belly covered with whipped cream.

Comment: Thanks, I added another photo from another section of the plaster, maybe that will help?

Comment: @Sycamore a hundred photos would not help ... if you are really concerned, then have it tested

Comment: I couldn’t answer this on the biology page (cross posted) due to the very strict guidelines there. There are fungi that are directly pathogenic and infect people, but They are all grey, white, or black. But any concentration of fungal spores should not be breathed in due to irritation or allergy problems. Let the plaster dry properly, and it will die off.

Comment: Pink fungus on cheese is on the recommended list for not eating either.

Comment: You have a contaminated jar. Trow it away. Any fungus loves dark and moist, = your jar.